# How to get the JLabels and JTextAreas to align to the top left of the screen not the center

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, gridbaglayout

```
public Panel(){
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;

    add(l1 , c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;

    add(tf1 , c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;

    add(l2 , c );

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;

    add(tf2 , c);
}
```

This what it currently looks like:
[image]

How do I align the content to the top left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anchors, they are part of GridBagConstraints class and they are used to tell Java where do components go. So for example if you want them to appear on the left top corner you just use:

```
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
```

You could also use

```
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
```

Altough I like more the first one. You can read more about this and see all the available options [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) at Oracle Documentation.

One thing more, anchors won't work if you don't give a value to weighty. If you don't asign a value as Java says all components will clump together on the center. Weighty can take values from 0 to 1. For example:

```
c.weighty = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following line after `c` declaration:

```
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JPanel below like this:

```
add(new JPanel(), new GridBagConstraints(0,2,2,1,1.0,1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(2,2,2,2),1,1));
```